# Sorting email in conversations with Outlook in iOS

Tags: ios, email, ms-office

In the latest release of Microsoft Outlook for iOS (as of 2/26/2015), is there a way to change the sort behavior of message within a conversation?

If I'm not mistaken, the messages are sorted from oldest to newest, which requires scrolling to see the most recent.  I'd like to change that to be newest to oldest so the most recent message is on top.

Is that possible?

Comment: While I don't see a setting to change this, my INBOX is sorted newest on top (i.e. Newest to Oldest). Now there is a setting for Focused Inbox that was on by default that only shows you the messages Outlook thinks are important. And an Organize by thread setting as well.

Comment: Right, but I'm talking explicitly about viewing a conversation.  From your INBOX, tap a message that's a conversation.  The view should be replaced by the list of messages in that conversation, and they'll be sorted oldest to newest.

Comment: Ahhh yea... I see what you mean. Don't think you can change that.

Comment: The Windows client sorts it the right way... oh well!